# How to send complex objects, arrays and DateTime through SOAP service in Android?

Tags: android, web-services, soap, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

Hi I'm a newbie and I never worked with SOAP services, actually the service is made by another person, so I don't know about the service, so far I'm Successful in sending an Integer and getting the response but i don't know how to handle the complex objects so please guide me..
the code is below:

```
    public String sendOrder(String METHOD_NAME) {
    String RESPONSE = "";
    try {
        Date dateTime = (Date) Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

        request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("ShopID", 0);
        request.addProperty("SaleDate", getSOAPDateString(dateTime));
        request.addProperty("UserID", 0);
        request.addProperty("POSCode", "string");
        request.addProperty("SaleID", 0);
        request.addProperty("TableID", 0);
        request.addProperty("TableDesc", "string");
        request.addProperty("TableStatus", "");

        SaleAndReturnDetailAndroid C = new SaleAndReturnDetailAndroid(0,0,1,0,false);
        PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
        pi.setName("SaleAndReturnDetailAndroid");
        pi.setValue(C);
        pi.setType(C.getClass());

        request.addProperty(pi);
        //request.addProperty(pi);

        //request.addProperty("LineItems", arrayList);
        envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.bodyOut = request;
        envelope.dotNet = true;

        httpRequest = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        httpRequest.debug = true;
        httpRequest.call(NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME, envelope);
        Log.v("Result ResPOnse", envelope.getResponse().toString());
        RESPONSE = envelope.getResponse().toString();
        Log.v("Result DONE", METHOD_NAME);
        // GetData(RESPONSE, METHOD_NAME);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("LINK_PARSER sendOrderInfo", e.toString());

    }
    return RESPONSE;
}
```

It gives me error:

```
10-29 15:15:54.887: E/LINK_PARSER sendOrderInfo(18354): java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: 0.0
```

the SOAP Service is like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <PlaceOrder xmlns="http://lumensoft.biz/">
      <order>
        <ShopID>int</ShopID>
        <SaleDate>dateTime</SaleDate>
        <UserID>int</UserID>
        <POSCode>string</POSCode>
        <SaleID>int</SaleID>
        <TableID>int</TableID>
        <TableDesc>string</TableDesc>
        <TableStatus>string</TableStatus>
        <LineItems>
          <SaleAndReturnDetailAndroid>
            <UnitPrice>double</UnitPrice>
            <Qty>double</Qty>
            <DishID>int</DishID>
            <AvgCost>double</AvgCost>
            <IsReturnItem>boolean</IsReturnItem>
          </SaleAndReturnDetailAndroid>
          <SaleAndReturnDetailAndroid>
            <UnitPrice>double</UnitPrice>
            <Qty>double</Qty>
            <DishID>int</DishID>
            <AvgCost>double</AvgCost>
            <IsReturnItem>boolean</IsReturnItem>
          </SaleAndReturnDetailAndroid>
        </LineItems>
      </order>
    </PlaceOrder>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

pardon my english.
I don't know if `LineItems` is a List or Object, 
and `SaleAndReturnDetailAndroid` is two times so I've to send it two times?
i think i'm doing everything wrong it.
I'm really depressed please help...

Comment: @Selvin I've looked everywhere......!!!!

Comment: @Selvin i've looked but i dont understand....! I've never worked with SOAP requests before

Comment: and I'll find something... its just the matter of time..